# Is it possible to import other xquery modules in marklogic CPF action module?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am using MarkLogic `CPF` framework.

When a document is inserted in a particular `collection` a XQuery module will be invoked let's say `create-doc.xqy`.

I have configured the domain to have all the xquery modules in `documents` database under path `/create/xquery/modules/*.xqy`

Path for `create-doc.xqy` will be `/create/xquery/modules/create-doc.xqy`

Is it possible to import other xquery modules in `create-doc.xqy` and use it's methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your description, it appears that the chapter related to importing modules is what you are looking for:

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/import_modules

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches to doing this

1. Just insert your xqy file in the MarkLogic Database on which the CPF is defined(not modules DB) and now you can refer it from the CPF actions.
2. The second method is to put the module in the "Modules" directory in MarkLogic installation folder. Now you can refer it from the CPF action same as you import search module to use "search:search" method.